# Sentences With Multiple Antecedents

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

Below I have provided three examples sentences with multiple antecedents and their respective pronoun(s). So, my question is as follows: How do I determine which antecedent the pronoun refers to?

- Dudley quickly found the largest snake in the place. **It** could have wrapped its body twice around Uncle Vernon‘s car and crushed **it** into a trash can – but at the moment **it** didn‘t look in the mood. In fact, **it** was fast asleep.
- For example, researchers interviewed selection specialists from 33 firms widely regarded to be at the forefront of research on managerial effectiveness in the 1960s, and found that all of **them** used only clinical combinations of **their** selection information.
- Prior to instituting the WOSBs, failure rates at Officer Cadet Training Units were at 20% to 30%, and many recruits who might have succeeded in training were rejected by the interview boards on the basis of such factors as which grammar school **they** attended or **their** perceived socialist opinions.

Comment: You have to use ***logic / common sense*** - generally speaking, working ***backwards*** from the pronoun and considering each possible referent until you find one that makes sense. In the first example, it's obvious "the place" couldn't wrap its body around anything, so you move back to "the largest snake". That makes sense, so you can stop looking for alternatives at that point. Note that *sometimes* a text genuinely is ambiguous in this respect (rarely, if it's from a competent writer).

Comment: ...Arguably your second example is ambiguous, because you *might* stop when you reach ***33 firms*** (which are quite capable of "using clinical combinations"). But in practice I doubt anyone cares whether ***them*** in the second example refers to the ***firms***, or to the ***specialists*** who work for those firms, so any "potential ambiguity" is of no consequence anyway.

Comment: It gets harder with say 'The dog lost track of the hare almost as soon as it saw it.' You just have to avoid unclear examples.